# Socket Buffer for bpf, __sk_buff

Tags: c

I am playing ebpf code  and got a sample like so:

```
int tc_ingress(struct __sk_buff *skb)
{
    void *data = (void *)(long)skb->data;
    struct ethhdr *eth = data, eth_copy; # what is this line doing? 
}
```

AS I am new to C and kernel, got stuck on many smaller things. Can some tell me what is this line mean?

```
struct ethhdr *eth = data, eth_copy;
```

Comment: How "new" are you to C exactly? That is just a cast from `void *` to a variable of type `struct ethhdr *`. Are you sure you don't want to read [a good C book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) first before diving into complex kernel code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
struct ethhdr *eth = data, eth_copy;
```

Is nothing special, it is a more compact version of

```c
struct ethhdr *eth = data; 
struct ethhdr *eth_copy;
```

So we declare two variables of the same type, but we initialize just the first one.